# Java Servlets with Thread is blocking?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I'm trying to use my own form of connection pooling to handle database connections but it seems to be blocking for some reason even though I used a thread, can someone help me point out my mistake please.

This is the servlet code with the thread class.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    OutputStream ostream = response.getOutputStream();
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(ostream, true, "UTF8");

    try {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String test = request.getParameter("test");
        System.out.println("Received text: " + test);

        if(test.equals("free"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                dbcm.freeConnection(list.get(i));
            }
            list.clear();
        }else
        {
            GetConnThread gct = new GetConnThread(test, dbcm);
            gct.start();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        out.println("fail");
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }

}



private class GetConnThread extends Thread
{
    private String test;
    private DBConnectionManager dbcm;

    public GetConnThread(String test, DBConnectionManager dbcm)
    {
        this.test = test;
        this.dbcm = dbcm;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try {
            Connection conn = dbcm.getConnection(test);
            list.add(conn);             
            System.out.println(conn);
            System.out.println("list size: " + list.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the getConnection method in the DBConnectionManager

```
    public synchronized Connection getConnection(String test) throws CGFatalException {
        Connection con = null;
        boolean connectionIsValid = false;
        if (freeConnections.size() > 0) {

            con = (Connection) freeConnections.firstElement();
            freeConnections.removeElementAt(0);

            connectionIsValid = validateConnection(con);
            if (connectionIsValid == false) {
                con = getConnection(test);
            }
        } else if (maxConn == 0 || checkedOut < maxConn) {
            con = newConnection();
            connectionIsValid = validateConnection(con);
            if (connectionIsValid == false) {
                con = getConnection(test);
            }
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("No available connections for " + test + ", try again in 2 secs....");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                con = getConnection(test);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (con != null && connectionIsValid == true) {
            checkedOut++;
        }
        System.out.println("checkedOut: " + checkedOut);
        System.out.println("maxConn: " + maxConn);
        return con;
    }
```

I set the max connections to 2 so after I call the servlet the 3rd time it goes to this line of code:

```
System.out.println("No available connections for " + test + ", try again in 2 secs....");
```

When I call it the 4th time, I'm expecting

```
System.out.println("No available connections for " + test + ", try again in 2 secs....");
```

to start as a seperate thread, but the 3rd call seems to be blocking it, the endless loop is expected because I was hoping to call "free" to clear the connections and everything goes back to normal.

Comment: I think you need to provide us with more information - probably a log file. You say _the endless loop is expected_, but you haven't shown us an endless loop. An _the 3rd call seems to be blocking it_, but there's no evidence for that, so we're having to rely on your guess work.

Comment: The "endless loop" is caused by the recursive call to try and get a "free" connection after the thread.sleep(2000).

Comment: Unless for pure hobby purposes, please do **not** homegrow connection pooling if you already don't understand how threading and concurrency work. Go pick an existing connection pool library. Every self-respected servletcontainer ships with builtin connection pooling facilities, Tomcat including. Make use of it. Really. Connection pooling is a too important artifact of a healthy webapplication which you don't want to homegrow with 0 understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getConnection method is synchronized.  Every other thread is going to block on that lock acquisition until the "third" request successfully gets a connection and proceeds.

Comment: Yes this is correct I just removed it and tested. If I remove the "synchonized" key word do you forsee and major problems I might face in terms of the counter for connections going haywire?

Comment: Looks like it would break without synchronization, yes.  Instead of synchronizing the entire method use a java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock so that you can release the lock before going to sleep.

Comment: Sorry Affe 1 last question, where would you put the lock() and unlock() so that I can better understand how locks work as opposed to synchronized.

Comment: Ok I understood what you meant after mucking around, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry I missed your last followup there, glad it worked out for you.